# Equilibrium points stable or unstable?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider
$x''=\frac{Gm_2}{(x-r)^2}-\frac{Gm_1}{x^2}$

> I want to determine the equilibrium point and answer the question if it is stable or unstable.

I solved $\frac{Gm_2}{(x-r)^2}=\frac{Gm_1}{x^2}$ and ended up with

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{r(m_1\pm\sqrt{m_1m_2})}{m_1-m_2}$$

I wrote the ODE as a system:

$$x'=\begin{pmatrix}x_0'\\x_1'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\frac{Gm_2}{(x_0-r)^2}-\frac{Gm_1}{x_0^2}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$f\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\x_1\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\frac{Gm_2}{(x_0-r)^2}-\frac{Gm_1}{x_0^2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$f\begin{pmatrix}\frac{r(m_1\pm\sqrt{m_1m_2})}{m_1-m_2}\\0\end{pmatrix}=0$$

How can I check if the equilibrium points are stable or unstable? (I know the definition of stable/unstable but I can't show it, unfortunately)

**Picture:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqASH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing the dynamic system

$$
x' = y\\
y' = \frac{G m_1}{(x-r)^2}-\frac{G m_2}{x^2}
$$

we have the equilibrium points

$$
p_1 = \left(\frac{r\sqrt{m_2}}{\sqrt{m_2}-\sqrt{m_1}},0\right)\\
p_2 = \left(\frac{r\sqrt{m_2}}{\sqrt{m_2}+\sqrt{m_1}},0\right)\\
$$

The jacobian is

$$
J = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{2 G m_2}{x^3}-\frac{2 G m_1}{(x-r)^3} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

at the equilibrium points those jacobians give

$$
J_{p_1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -\alpha & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and

$$
J_{p_2} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 \beta & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with $\alpha = \frac{2 G \left(\sqrt{m_1}-\sqrt{m_2}\right)^4}{\sqrt{m_1} \sqrt{m_2} r^3} \ge 0$ and $\beta = \frac{2 G \left(\sqrt{m_1}+\sqrt{m_2}\right)^4}{\sqrt{m_1} \sqrt{m_2} r^3} > 0$

with respective eigenvalues

$$
J_{p_1}\to (-i\sqrt\alpha,i\sqrt\alpha)\\
J_{p_2}\to (-\sqrt\beta,\sqrt\beta)
$$

So $p_1$ is probably a center and $p_2$ is a saddle point. The qualification of $p_1$ is obtained examining a movement integral. This integral can be obtained as follows:

$$
\frac{y'}{x'} = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{G m_1}{(x-r)^2}-\frac{G m_2}{x^2}}{y}
$$

then

$$
y y' = \frac 12\frac{d}{dx}y^2 = -\frac{d}{dx}\frac{G m_1}{x-r}+\frac{d}{dx}\frac{G m_2}{x}
$$

and integrating

$$
\frac 12y^2 + \frac{G m_1}{x-r}-\frac{G m_2}{x} = C
$$

Attached a plot for the level curves of this integral for the values

$$ G=1,m_1=1,m_2=4,r=1$$

In red the equilibrium points

[image]

here we can observe closed orbits around $p_1$ qualifying it as a center.

NOTE

If $m_1 = m_2$ we have only one equilibrium point which is $p_2 =(\frac{\sqrt{m_2} r}{\sqrt{m_1}+\sqrt{m_2}},0)$ which is a saddle point.

Comment: In the second line at $y'=...$ you mixed up $m_2$ and $m_1$ and I don't know if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are correct.

Using $y'=\frac{Gm_2}{(x-r)^2}-\frac{Gm_1}{x^2}$ I arrive at $p_{1,2}=\frac{r(m_1\pm \sqrt{m_1m_2})}{(m_1-m_2)}$

But I think I understood the concept now

Comment: @user675838 Yes.  It is a mere index change. The qualitative results are the same.

Comment: Okay I added a picture in my post. In $J_{p_1}$ the term at the bottom left can become $0$. Instead of being $-\alpha<0$ as you stated. Does that change anything in the case it actually is equal to zero?

Comment: @user675838 Thanks for the observation. now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to calculate the Jacobian matrix of the first-order system you've constructed, and then check the eigenvalues of it when evaluating the Jacobian at your equilibrium points.

Eigenvalues with real positive parts will indicate linear instability, whereas eigenvalues with negative real parts indicate linear stability.